# How can I read a zip file from Google Drive using Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm building a Google App Maker app which will allow the user to select a zip file from Google Drive, unzip the file and load it into a database.  I found the follow script which I've tried calling in a server script but I'm getting the error ""gapi" is not defined".   I've tried adding 'https://apis.google.com/js/plus.js?onload=init' as an external resource on the project settings page but didn't resolve the issue.  I'm guessing there must be an 'App Maker' way of using the Drive API to do this just haven't find a sample that shows how.

```
function downloadFile(fileUrl, callback) {
  if (fileUrl) {
    console.log('fileUrl: ' + fileUrl);
    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      callback(null);
    };
    xhr.send();
  } else {
    console.log('No file Url received.');
    callback(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason is that the snippet provided is intended for the client and not for the server. If you wish to do it in appmaker, I recomment you to use either the DriveApp https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app or the Drive service https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive